# What causes Entity Framework to create a table for a base class?

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, xaf

I keep falling into the trap of declaring an abstract base class for my tables and then finding that the base class is created by the data migration.

I know not to create a `DBSet` in the context for the table I don't want

The following class does not cause a `BasicBo` table to create

```
public abstract class BasicBo : IXafEntityObject  //, IObjectSpaceLink  we should just declare it when we really need it... mainly we want out business objects to be like POCOs 
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual void OnCreated()
    {
    }

    public virtual void OnSaving()
    {
    }

    public virtual void OnLoaded()
    {
    }
}
```

However this class does cause a `BasicNodeBo` table to be created

```
public abstract class BasicNodeBo : IXafEntityObject 
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual int SiblingOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual string Sequence { get; set; }

    public virtual void RecalculateSequence()
    {
    }

    public virtual void AddDependency(IObjectSpace os, BasicNodeBo sibling)
    {
    }

    public virtual void OnCreated()
    {
    }

    public virtual void OnSaving()
    {
    }

    public virtual void OnLoaded()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the presence of BasicNodeBo as a persistant navigation property in a business object..